# Remove element at specific screen width with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a responsive site with a mobile first approach where i need to add a html element when the screen is larger than 641px and remove when less. The problem i'm having is when i resize my screen larger than 641px the code produces infinite numbers of said element and when i reduce the screen size there is masses amounts of space when they are removed.

my code looks like this:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $(window).resize(function () {
                if ($(window).width() > 641) {
                     $('.project_nav').append('<li><a class="work_grid" href="#"><img src="images/noun_project_5193.svg"/> </a></li>');
                } else {
                    $('.work_grid').remove();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And here's the html i want to append:

```
<div class="project_nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="up_arrow" href="#"><img src="images/noun_project_6978.svg"/> </a></li>
                <li><a class="prev_arrow" href="#"><img src="images/noun_project_6976.svg"/> </a></li>
                <li><a class="next_arrow" href="#"><img src="images/noun_project_6977.svg"/> </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe try adding a boolean javascript flag that is set to false on page load, and true the first time the resize function is run. Check the flag at the top of your resize function before running.

Comment: Why use javascript to do this when you can just use a css media query? Edit: I guess if you want to save bandwidth on the client that would make sense.

Comment: @dhsto in regards to media queries, i was finding it difficult add and remove the element without it creating empty space in the design. Is there a way around that?

Comment: That's weird. Usually just doing `display: none` will make it seem like it's not there to the user. Maybe you were doing `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0`? I don't know, it would be difficult without seeing your code.

Comment: I'll give it another go. Thanks for the help anyway, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep track of if the element has already been added or removed. Easiest way without pounding the dom is to store this in a variable:

```
    $(function () {
        var isAdded = false;
        $(window).resize(function () {
            if (!isAdded && $(window).width() > 641) {
                 isAdded = true;
                 $('.project_nav').append('<li class="work_grid_container"><a class="work_grid" href="#"><img src="images/noun_project_5193.svg"/> </a></li>');
            } else if (isAdded && $(window).width() <= 641) {
                isAdded = false;
                $('.work_grid_container').remove();
            }
        });
    });
```

This way it will only add the element if it hasn't already been added and it will remove it only if it currently exists on the page.

**Note**: You need to have a selector for the `li` instead of the `a`! Otherwise you will keep adding `li`s. You need to fully remove what you added.

Comment: You should probably set the variable back to false if you remove the element yes?

Comment: Yes thanks, I just added that additional step along with the note.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that when you resize, you are actually resizing a whole bunch, adding way too many elements.  What you want to do is add some sort of `Timeout`.  Here is an example.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    clearTimeout(window.refresh_size);
    window.refresh_size = setTimeout(function () {
        //Do stuff
    }, 100);
```

This way, it will only do your code after you have stopped resizing the page for a least 100 ms.